# How to write two python dictionaries with common key to CSV file?

Tags: python

I have the below two dictionaries:
dict1 = {'a':100,'b':200,'c':300}
dict2 = {'a':0.20,'b':0.25,'c':0.30}

I want to write it into CSV as :

Key Value1 Value2
a   100     0.20
b   200     0.25
c   300     0.30

Comment: Are the keys in both dictionaries *exactly* the same, or is there only partial overlap?

Comment: they are exactly the same

Answer (score 1):

#### Dictionaries with identical key sets

```
dict1 = {'a':100,'b':200,'c':300} 
dict2 = {'a':0.20,'b':0.25,'c':0.30}

with open('some_file','w') as f:
    f.write('Key\tValue1\tValue2\n')
    for k in sorted(dict1.keys()):
        f.write("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\n".format(k,dict1[k],dict2[k]))
```

This iterates over one key set, and prints out values from both dictionaries. (Bonus: works in both Python 2 and Python 3.)

#### Dictionaries with disjoint key sets

For anyone who was hoping to find an answer to the question where there are potentially multiple dictionaries, and potentially *disjoint* keysets, here's a (somewhat hacky) answer:

```
dict1 = {'a':100,'b':200,'c':300} 
dict2 = {'a':0.20,'b':0.25,'c':0.30,'d':0.40}
dict3 = {'a':2000,'b':2500,'d':9000,'e':9500}

with open('some_file','w') as f:
    f.write('Key\tValue1\tValue2\tValue3\n')
    keys_union = set(dict1.keys()).union(set(dict2.keys())).union(set(dict3.keys()))
    for k in sorted(keys_union):
        f.write("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\n".format( k,
                        [dict1[k] if k in dict1.keys() else "-"][0],
                        [dict2[k] if k in dict2.keys() else "-"][0],
                        [dict3[k] if k in dict3.keys() else "-"][0]))
```

This prints a "-" for values that are missing from one of the dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the dictionaries to a [pandas data-frame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html), i.e.
```

```
from tabulate import tabulate
import pandas as pd

dict1 = {'a':100,'b':200,'c':300} 
dict2 = {'a':0.20,'b':0.25,'c':0.30}

df = pd.Series(dict1,name='Value 1').to_frame()
df['Value 2'] = dict2.values()
print(tabulate(df, headers= 'keys', tablefmt= 'grid'))
```

printing df generates

```
+----+-----------+-----------+
|    |   Value 1 |   Value 2 |
+====+===========+===========+
| a  |       100 |      0.2  |
+----+-----------+-----------+
| b  |       200 |      0.25 |
+----+-----------+-----------+
| c  |       300 |      0.3  |
+----+-----------+-----------+
```

A pandas series is a 1D data structure which converts the dictionary `dict1` to a series with the dictionary keys as the index and the dictionary values as the series values. `to_frame` converts the series to a dataframe (2D data structure or a table) with one column, the line `df['Value 2'] = dict2.values()` adds `dict2` as a second column in the dataframe `df`.
You can write the resulting dataframe to a csv file using

```
df.to_csv('filename here')
```

here is the result of dumping the file content using `cat`
[image: image of the result of dumping the file content to screen]

PS. tabulate simply convert the dataframe to decorated text for printing purposes

Edit:
This is overkill but;
to get the exact output, the index can be reset/renamed then `to_csv` parameter `index` is set to `False`; meaning the index is not to be stored
[image]